# QML WebEngine how enable scroll animation

Tags: qt, scroll, qml, qtwebengine

The QWebEngineSettings class has the ScrollAnimatorEnabled attribute, but WebEngineSettings (QML) does not have this property. How to enable smooth scrolling in WebEngineView?

Comment: Looks like a bug or weaknesses. For some reason they provide `QWebEngineSettings::WebAttribute` flags as properties. It looks like they just missed few flags.

Answer (score 0):

can run the program with the --enable-smooth-scrolling argument or like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<char*> argv2(argc + 1);
    argv2.reserve(argc + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
        argv2.emplace_back(argv[i]);
    argv2.emplace_back(const_cast<char*>("--enable-smooth-scrolling"));
    argc = int(argv2.size());
    argv = argv2.data();
    
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    ...
```